# Shell script to Delete Folders and Zip files in a folder which contains same name

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I came across scenario using shell script. I need to delete the folder and Zip if it has the same name. Can any one please help me in this .

**Example**

Below is the directory path in which script need to search the same name in the directory (here it needs to print and delete example and `example.zip`)

```
Path:/tmp/test/
/tmp/test/example
/tmp/test/example.zip
/tmp/test/zack
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
parent_dir=/tmp/test/
for i in `ls /tmp`
do
        if [[ $i != *.zip ]]; then
                if [[ -f /tmp/$i.zip ]]; then
                        array=$array" "$i
                fi
        fi
done
array=( $array )
for i in ${array[@]}
do
        rm -r $parent_dir$i
        rm -r $parent_dir$i".zip"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the script

Answer (score 0):

This should do a trick, even suitable for a cronjob:

```
find $DIR_PATH -type d -exec sh -c '[ -f "{}.zip" ] && rm -fr {}.zip {}' \;
```

Just set DIR_PATH to where youre searching